# Schema.org for acronym / abbreviation (in a glossary)

Tags: schema.org, glossary

I'd like to mark my list of acronyms/abbreviations in my glossary of my website with Schema.org (using Microdata).

Which type of Schema.org is the right one for that?

I can't find any related type in the [full list on schema.org](https://schema.org/docs/full.html).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The type [**`DefinedTerm`**](https://schema.org/DefinedTerm) (which is [currently in Pending](https://pending.schema.org/DefinedTerm), so it’s subject to change) is suitable for a

> word, name, acronym, phrase, etc. with a formal definition

In a glossary, you would use the `name` property for the term, and the `description` property for what the term stands for.

```html
<p itemscope itemtype="https://schema.org/DefinedTerm">
  <span itemprop="name">SO</span>: 
  <span itemprop="description">Stack Overflow</span>
</p>
```

Or with semantic markup:

```html
<dl>

  <div itemscope itemtype="https://schema.org/DefinedTerm">
    <dt itemprop="name"><dfn><abbr>SO</abbr></dfn></dt>
    <dd itemprop="description">Stack Overflow</dd>
  </div>

</dl>
```

(For the whole glossary, you could use the type [`DefinedTermSet`](https://schema.org/DefinedTermSet), and add each entry with the property [`inDefinedTermSet`](https://schema.org/inDefinedTermSet).)

Comment: Oh wow, I had no idea it is now allowed to put a `div` inside a `dl` directly. This makes some styling challenges *a lot* less challenging.